# Bizarre case of one change making canvas event not listen

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I started re-writing Windows!
The code below draws 10 canvas objects you can move around. I made them random sizes.
When you click on one it has thicker outline and can be dragged around.

When I added one line to change the initial top position of the canvases the move stopped working.
Its very odd, I only wanted to stack the windows in increasing 10px steps rather then them all starting at the same spot.
Why could this minor change stop the rest working?

```js
var n = 0,
  canv = [],
  ct = []
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var targ, wind = 10,
  i, offx, offy = 0
for (n = 0; n < wind; n++) {
  canv[n] = document.createElement('canvas');
  canv[n].id = "C" + n;
  canv[n].width = rnd(30 * n);
  canv[n].height = rnd(30 * n);
  //canv[n].style.top=10*n     <- This line stops the drag effect working
  canv[n].style.zIndex = n;
  canv[n].style.position = "absolute";
  canv[n].style.border = "2px solid";

  body.appendChild(canv[n]);
 targ=canv[0]    // added now to stop errors before first click
  ct[n] = canv[n].getContext("2d");
  ct[n].fillText(n, canv[n].width / 2, canv[n].height / 2)

  canv[n].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    targ = e.currentTarget
    if (targ.style.border == "2px solid") {
      for (i = 0; i < wind; i++) {
        canv[i].style.border = "2px solid"
      }
      targ.style.border = "5px solid";
      offy = e.y - targ.style.top
    } else {
      targ.style.border = "2px solid"
    }
  });
  canv[n].addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (targ.style.border == "5px solid") {
      move(e.x, e.y)
    }
  });
}

function move(x, y) {
  targ.style.top = y - offy
}

function rnd(m) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * m)
}
```

Comment: You really should add and remove a class instead of setting styles and checking styles

Comment: targ is not set until you click your mouse so the mousemove throws tons of errors.

Comment: ah Epascarello, how do I add a class?

Comment: @EV123 Using the [`classList` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), but since everything is calculated, I recommend [using CSS custom properties (variables)](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) instead. [`top`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top) requires a [`<length>`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) or a [`<percentage>`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/percentage). You’re setting it to a [`<number>`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/number) instead. [Make a string](/q/1408289/4642212).

Comment: @Sebastian, ok so I tried  
 canv[n].style.top=n+'%'
That didnt work either!

Comment: @EV123 That’s not the only place. That’s also not the only mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a global variable for when it is active. That is not set until a click happens so you get tons of errors.

When you are setting a position, it needs some sort of units.

Basic idea with the code cleaned up a bit.

```js
const canv = [];
const ct = [];

const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

let targ, wind = 10,
  i, offx, offy = 0;

for (let n = 0; n < wind; n++) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canv[n] = canvas;
  
  canvas.id = "C" + n;

  const width = rnd(30 * n);
  const height = rnd(30 * n);
  
  canvas.style.width = width + "px";
  canvas.style.height = height + "px";
  canvas.style.top = (10 * n) + "px";
  canvas.style.left = (10 * n) + "px";
  canvas.style.zIndex = n;
  
  body.appendChild(canvas);

  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ct[n] = ctx;
  ctx.fillText(n, width / 2, height / 2)

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll("canvas.active").forEach(elem => {
      elem.classList.remove("active");
    });
    targ = e.currentTarget;
    targ.classList.add("active");
  });

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (targ && targ.classList.contains('active')) {
      move(e.x, e.y)
    }
  });
}

function move(x, y) {
  targ.style.top = y - offy + "px"
}

function rnd(m) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * m)
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: 1;
}

canvas.active {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: One thing I dont get, in your code clean up you added
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ct[n] = ctx;

I thought const cant be redefined, and its in a loop so const will be set 10 different times, so how can it redifine that const?
Whats the advantage to putting it to a const before adding it to the array anyway

Comment: const is redefined in a block. Each iteration of the loop is a new variable.